# Higher gain at higher frequency in instrumental amplifiers

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, texas-instruments

I am using an instrumentation amplifiers (INA181). When the gain (G) is set to 10000 the behavior is as expected. However, when G is set to 1k there is an increase in the output signal going with the frequency. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Wikepedia [gain-bandwith product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain%E2%80%93bandwidth_product) (The trick for this sort of effects is that you have to know the right search phrase. )

Comment: @oldfart thank you for your answer. The thing is that I am just seeing the opposite, I am observing an increase in the gain with the frequency, not a decrease as should be expected. I think it may be related with the resistors that I am using at the input terminals, I am trying to confirm that.